# What is a "Suzuka" Honda CR-V?

Tags: honda, trim

When looking for parts for my old 2000 Honda CR-V, there are eight possible trim choices, with half having the word Suzuka:

2000, Honda CR-V, 5-door, Trim:

- EX
- EX (Suzuka)
- LX 2WD
- LX 2WD (Suzuka)
- LX 4WD
- LX 4WD (Suzuka)
- SE
- SE (Suzuka)

I've been doing some web searches trying to figure out what Suzuka means. Apparently there is a Japanese manufacturing plant in a place called Suzuka, but this seems meaningless as there are multiple other manufacturing plants.

If it is or isn't a Suzuka version, how would I know that and is this marked on the vehicle somewhere? I live in the USA, if that matters at all.

Comment: I have no idea, google is for once not helpful at all. Call a dealer and ask would be my advice, you could also try the CRV owners forum: http://www.crvownersclub.com

Comment: what trim level are you at now? does the tailgate have badging on it?  FWIW I've never seen a Suzuka badged CR-V and the wiki doesn't mention it at all. enter your vin into this https://honda-tech.com/forums/vindecoder.php and see what it says.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely a model name linked to the Suzuka circuit - there was probably a race that they won around the time or an anniversary of a race that they won.

Comment: A marketing name, edited out bike sorry, like Chevrolet Monza or Ferrari Daytona, Bentley Brooklands

Comment: Or VW Wolfsburg Edition

Answer (score 0):

It's a factory in japan more info here [link](http://world.honda.com/group/production/sites/suzuka/)

Comment: Honda doesn't build the CRV in Suzuka.

Comment: Technically not true, they did build a few 2.0 liter engines that were shared between the S2000 and CR-V. Hence the S2000 swapped Suzuka engines were placed in the V.